# GLM Precompile Error In Julia Pro 1.0/1.2

Tags: julia, glm

Hello internet friends,

I am using the Julia Pro v.1.0.5-2 IDE to render animations for some Condensed Matter Physics data. When I attempt to run:

```
array = load("C:/Users/Kyle/Desktop/julia/data/Psi_L=89_W=0_0.01_500000-500/Psi_L=89_W=0_g=0.0_L^2.jld", "data")
@gif for i=1:7
    array_2 = abs2.(array[i][:,:,1])
    x=1:89
    y=1:89
    f(x,y) = array_2[x,y]
    plot(x,y,f,st=:surface,camera=(0,30), title = "Wavefunction Density Animation, L=89, g=0, t = $(5*i)")
end
```

I get the following error:

```
[ Info: Precompiling GLM [38e38edf-8417-5370-95a0-9cbb8c7f171a]

ERROR: LoadError: No deps.jl file could be found. Please try running Pkg.bui
Currently, the build command might fail when Julia has been built from sourc
and the recommendation is to use the official binaries from julialang.org.
For more info see https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl/issues/5.

ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Failed to precompile Arpack [7d9fca2a-8960-54d3aPro_v1.0.5-2\compiled\v1.0\Arpack\X5VZL.ji.

in expression starting at C:\Users\Kyle\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.5-2\packages
in expression starting at C:\Users\Kyle\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.5-2\packages
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile PDMats [90014a1f-27ba-587c-ab20-58faa-2\compiled\v1.0\PDMats\wuzEE.ji.

in expression starting at C:\Users\Kyle\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.5-2\packages
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile Distributions [31c24e10-a181-5473-b8e_v1.0.5-2\compiled\v1.0\Distributions\xILW0.ji.

in expression starting at C:\Users\Kyle\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.5-2\packages
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile GLM [38e38edf-8417-5370-95a0-9cbb8c7fcompiled\v1.0\GLM\6OREG.ji.
```

When I attempt to run:

`Pkg.build("Arpack")`

I get the following error:

```
Pkg.build("Arpack")
  Building Arpack → `C:\Users\Kyle\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.5-2\packages\Arpa
┌ Error: Error building `Arpack`: 
│ ┌ Warning: Platform `x86_64-w64-mingw32-libgfortran4` is not an officially
│ └ @ BinaryProvider C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.5\share\julia\st
```

It is important to mention that I had produced several animations with no problems with the same exact code. I stopped to go through some emails and when I tabbed back and ran the code with new parameters, it broke as I described. Furthermore, all the relevant packages are installed (except the ones that threw these errors) and "using [xpackage]" are sprinkled in appropriately.

Thanks for taking the time to read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Arpack >=0.3.2` is incompatible with JuliaPro 1.2.0-1. To work aound this issue, you can either `] add Arpack@0.3.1` or install JuliaPro version 1.2.0-2.